# Возможно ли из под yii2 создать базу данных

Tags: php, sql, база-данных, yii2

Получил вот такое задание:

> Реализовать на yii или yii2 следующий функционал: 3)  Написать класс
>   взаимодействия с БД(желательно postgreSQL), для класса реализовать
>   методы:
>
> - Create – создает БД, входные параметры, название таблицы, и массив состоящий из  названия поля, тип данных поля, доп. Данные поля(not
>     null, primary key к примеру).

Теперь умом понять не могу как такое из под yii2 осуществить это. Ведь в настройках yii2 в конфиге уже указывается используемая БД и как создать новую базу мне непонятно, ведь для этого нужны root права на СУБД.

Вопрос такой: это я не понимаю задания или само задание не выполнимо?

Comment: ну судя по `входные параметры, название таблицы, и массив состоящий из названия поля, тип данных поля, доп` может все таки надо создать таблицу. А в тексте должно было быть написано "создает **в** БД". Думаю лучше уточнить у тех, кто дал задание.

Comment: и я так же рассуждаю как и вы. просто до сдачи задания осталось ~30 часов. а вопросы они просят задавать по эмейлу, потеряю время и останусь с носом.

Comment: @perfect решайте исходя из того, что у вас есть права на создание базы данных. Задача действительно может быть полезна, например, когда вы автоматически развертываете приложение в контейнере или в тестовом окружении. Если на продакшене прав не будет - ваша задача просто не будет работать.

Comment: можно посмотреть как работают миграции в yii2 для postgres, создания БД там само собой нет, но может в целом даст идею.

Comment: @StalkAlex и об этом подумал, но мало вероятно что это имели бы ввиду в задании для стажера. но ваша мысль логически правильная.

Comment: Предположу, что задача поставлена некорректно. Так как само понятие создание БД относится не к фреймворку а к админ части. А таблицу можно запросто создать. Что скорее всего и требовалось с помощью **QueryBuilder** сделать или с помощью **Command**

Comment: Может HR просто хочет посмотреть, можете вы отличить корректно поставленную задачу от некорректной? Если HR будет утверждать, что задача корректная, то я бы туда работать не шел :)

Comment: Насколько мне известно из Laravel, у у фреймвоков есть обертка для обращения к базе данных. http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/ru/database.query-builder.

Answer (score 1):

Понимаю что опоздал с ответом, но отвечу. То что в конфиге при подключении мы указываем имя базы данных в DSN, всего лишь говорит что это база у нас по умолчанию для приложения и никак не запрещает нам работать с другими базами вплоть до создания таковых.

Давайте поглядим пример DSN

```
$db = [
    'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
    'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db1',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'charset' => 'utf8',
];
```

Мы указываем приложению что будем подключаться по умолчанию к `db1`.
Но что нам мешает сделать такой запрос из приложения?

```
SELECT db1.users.id, db2.firms.id 
FROM db1.users 
JOIN db2.firms ON db1.users.firm_id = db2.firms.id
```

Будет подключена таблица из другой базы данных и запрос успешно выполнится. Главное чтобы прав хватило.

Также мы можем создать например миграцию следующего вида

```
<?php

use yii\db\Migration;

class m170219_083615__ extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        $this->execute("CREATE DATABASE test2");
    }
}
```

И эта миграция тоже будет выполнена успешно. 
Главное чтобы у нашего текущего пользователя были права на создание баз данных.

Comment: если есть доступ к консоли, проще все это сделать с помощью PHP без yii с помощью функции shell_exec